# Custom Tab Button Won't Connect to Macro

Tags: excel, vba, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a custom tab to run macros following directions from [here](https://wellsr.com/vba/2019/excel/how-to-make-custom-vba-ribbons-in-excel/). I've followed the steps but run into trouble when I try to click the button. I'm receiving the message: `Cannot run macro 'hello'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.` the modification to the .rels file looks like: `<Relationship Id="metrics" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2007/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="/CustomUI/trial_CustomUI.xml"/>` The folder and file names match `Target`. The XML file looks like:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon> 
        <tabs> 
            <tab id="CustomTab" label="My Tab"> 
                <group id = "hello" label = "Hello">
                    <button id = "hi" label =  "Hello" imageMso = "ShapeSmileyFace" size = "large" onAction = "hello"/>
                </group>
            </tab> 
        </tabs> 
    </ribbon> 
</customUI>
```

The ribbon macro looks like:

```
Option Explicit

Public MyRibbon As IRibbonUI

Public Sub ControlRibbon(Ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set MyRibbon = Ribbon
End Sub
```

The macro looks like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Hello(control As IRibbonControl)
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

All the answers I have come across relate to modifying the `Trust access to the VBA project object model`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: @Peyter 's answer was instrumental in allowing me to arrive at the answer. However, I did need to make some minor syntax changes in order to get it to work:

1. Instead of `Macro()` VBA defaulted to `Macro`
2. Instead of `OnAction="Workbookname.xlsm!Control_Macroname"` I used `OnAction="Workbookname.xlsm!Control_Macroname.Control_Macroname"`

With these modifications I was able to get the button on the ribbon to work.

Comment: Well done my dude!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this is a tough one, you're almost there.

Here's what you need to do with your 3 parts

Assuming your wb is named:  workbookname.xlsm

Part 1 example wb xml References Control macro(function) Name:

```
OnAction="Workbookname.xlsm!Control_Macroname"
```

Part 2 Ribbon Control Macro(function):

```
Sub Control_Macroname(control as IRibbonControl)
   Call Macro()
End Sub
```

Part 3 Macro to actually run:

```
Sub Macro()
   'do stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: is there anything I can clarify to help you implement this? If I've answered your question adequately. Please mark the post answered and upvote : )

Comment: I apologize for not reviewing this sooner. I will definitely mark this as accepted as soon as I have an opportunity to get it working.

Comment: no worries dude, just let me know if anything still isnt working. I used to use this set up a lot before VSTO made tab / ribbon stuff real easy. It's still fun to make a cool ribbon with custom macros in Excel.

Comment: Thanks @Peyter. I'm still having trouble with the Ribbon Control Macro. Pressing the button on the ribbon returns the message `Cannot run 'Workbookname.xlsm!Control_Macroname'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.`

Comment: After a few more attempts I was able to get it to work with some minor syntax changes. I'll modify my answer to highlight these but will still give you credit for the answer since I would not have been able to arrive at the solution without your help.